# Windows Service: Define asynchnous method that runs after startup - SignalR Client

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr

I have a Windows Service that is bare-bones. I need it to be a SignalR Client. The SignalR startup code includes an await so I need an asynchronous method. I can't put it in the OnStart method, yet I need this to happen after the startup has occured.

The SignalR code would be something like:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock => Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price));
await hubConnection.Start();
```

How do I this having it run after startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
            try
            {
                var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/AlphaFrontEndService/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
                IHubProxy alphaProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("AlphaHub");

                await hubConnection.Start();
                // Invoke method on hub
                await alphaProxy.Invoke("Hello", "Message from Service");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If OnStart itself can't be async, you can simply put the above code in another async method that is called from OnStart. You can then choose to use Task.Wait or Task.ContinueWith when you call the async method in OnStart depending on whether you want to block or not block.